# How can I implement a webpage div like region in winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to implement something in `winform` like below: which was implemented in webpage, and after clicking the "Size" button, will show another region underneath.

Can I use `datagridview`? or `listview`?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by 'region'?

Comment: Do you mean *dynamically positioned* (shown/hidden)? Check [`TableLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx).

Comment: yes, dynamically positioned.

Answer (score 0):

Go for the [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

It allows you to add and remove controls while they will float to the left or the the right just how you configure it